# how to close the child window when closing parent window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parent

How to close the child window when closing parent window in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

If by parent and child windows you mean a pop-up window and the window that opened it, you can't do exactly this, but the following script in the main window will close the pop-up window when the main window is unloaded (i.e. either closed or the user navigates to another page or refreshes):

```
var popUp = window.open("popup.html", "popup", "width=300,height=200");

window.onunload = function() {
    if (popUp && !popUp.closed) {
        popUp.close();
    }
};
```

Historical note: it used to be possible to do this in some browsers (e.g. Firefox) by using the `dependent` window property in the third parameter of the `window.open` call (e.g. `var popUp = window.open("popup.html", "popup", "width=300,height=200,dependent");`) but [according to quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html) it's no longer supported in anything. I haven't tested this myself.

Answer (score 0):

When multiple child windows are opened form one window and you want to close all of them when parent window is closed, then you need to store child window references in array. On window's onunload event you can iterate this array and call close() method on each child window reference. To see complete example [**click here**](http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-close-child-windows-when-closing.html)

```
window.onunload = function closeChildWin(){
 for(var i=0; i<childwindows.length; i++){
  try{
     childwindows[i].close()
  }catch(e){
   alert(e);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while creating popups from within popups. Accessing a windows name after it's been created seemed to do nothing.

First a window is created:

```
popup = window.open(address, name, params)
```

First I was trying to do this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    popup.close()
}
```

But the problem is that the name 'popup' couldn't be accessed after it was created. I was getting no response.

So this is how I got it working. Inside the javascript for the popup window I added:

```
window.parent.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.close()
}
```

Now, whenever the parent window is close, all "child" windows are closed as well. even if there are popups under popups under popups. As long as each "popup" window has this, it closes when any window "above" it closes.